# How to encrypt and decrypt data without exposing keys with client using socket.io,nodejs, and vanilla js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, socket.io

I'm making a web chat app should I encrypt and decrypt messages on client or I should rely on tcl if I should encrypt then how can I do this without exposing anything on client.

I am using nodejs, socket.io, and vanilla JavaScript. I am seeking some code samples.

Comment: Use WebSockets. Then you can use SSL to encrypt it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common solution here is asymmetric encryption using public key cryptography where you share the server's public key with the client and the client shares it's public key with you.  Private keys are not shared.  The client uses the server's public key to encrypt data and the server uses its private key to decrypt.  Vice versa when sending data the other way.  This is a hassle to implement yourself securely entirely in Javascript and it's easy to make mistakes that introduce vulnerabilities.

But, fortunately, you don't have to do that because if you just use `https` as your transport for your socket.io connection, then all the public key cryptography is completely done for you (in the TLS implementation that https uses) and you have not only a fully encrypted end-to-end channel to send your messages over, but you also have domain spoofing protection too since browsers will verify that server certificates match the URL being used.

**So, just make your socket.io connection over https and you're done.**